# Parameters for Optimizer in ShuffleNet

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

In ShuffleNet the parameters that send to the optimizer first pass from the following function which makes a dictionary of weights:

```
def get_parameters(model):
    group_no_weight_decay = []
    group_weight_decay = []
    for pname, p in model.named_parameters():
        if pname.find('weight') >= 0 and len(p.size()) > 1:
            # print('include ', pname, p.size())
            group_weight_decay.append(p)
        else:
            # print('not include ', pname, p.size())
            group_no_weight_decay.append(p)
    assert len(list(model.parameters())) == len(group_weight_decay) + len(group_no_weight_decay)
    groups = [dict(params=group_weight_decay), dict(params=group_no_weight_decay, weight_decay=0.)]
    return groups
```

and then:

```
optimizer = optim.Adam(get_parameters(model), lr=0.01)
```

But what is the difference between this function and just using `model.parameters`  instead of `get_parameters(model)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `model.parameters()` yo get *all* the parameters of the model in a single "group", and thus all hyper parameters of the optimizer are the same for all `model.parameters()`.

In contrast, `get_parameters()` groups `model.parameters()` into two groups: `group_weight_decay` and `group_no_weight_decay`. As the names suggest, for the parameters of the second group the optimizer sets the `weight_decay` hyper parameter to zero.